# What is the simplest proof that $\sqrt{n}^\sqrt{n}$ is transcendental when $n$ is not a square? What is the most elegant proof?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, transcendental-numbers

Consider the following question -*Are there two irrational numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a^{b}$ is rational?*- Well, suppose $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is rational, then we are done. If we suppose it is irrational, then  $\left(\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}\right)^\sqrt{2}$ is rational, and we are done again. In either case there is a solution, so the answer to the question is affirmative.

However, which one is it? One has to engage in some serious number theory in order to decide. That is, to show that $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational. In fact, it is transcendental; as the number $\sqrt{n}^{\sqrt{n}}$ is for any positive integers $n$ that is not a square.

What is the simplest (elementary) proof of this fact? And the most elegant?

Comment: Why do you say "then $\left( \sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{\sqrt{2}}$ is rational"?

Comment: @achillehui.... but $\sqrt{4}$ is *NOT* irrational, as demanded.

Comment: How about $\left(\sqrt{10}\right)^{log\left(4\right)}=10^{0.5\:log\left(4\right)}=10^{log\left(2\right)}=2$

Comment: Yes, obviously $n$ is not a square. I edited the question appropriately.

Comment: It is not at all easy to show that $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$ is irrational. Note that irrationality proofs are in general extremely difficult. Witness : The many unknown cases like $\gamma$ , $e+\pi$ , $e\cdot \pi$ , $e^e$ and many more.

Comment: @Peter Most certainly, which is why I was looking to see if there was a proof not involving some serious number theory. It is not even known whether $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}^\sqrt{2}}$ is rational or irrational.